# How do I edit the Cinnamon panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

I am stuck here as to how I change this image from dull gray to my desired preference. I was able to correctly apply the oxygen image from kde5 for the overall appearance of the panel, yet I have not been able to correct the image seen here in gray.

[image]

Am I even in the correct section of the cinnamon.css to make the changes? Any assistance here is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The section you are searching for is under "Group Window List"